# Which version of Hibernate is suited for Spring 4.3.2?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-4

I use `Spring` framework 4.3.2.RELEASE

I saw on a tutorial site that both `Spring` and `Hibernate` must match their versions in order to integrate `Hibernate` with `Spring`.

So what is the appropriate version of `Hibernate` for `Spring` 4.3.2.RELEASE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the link https://spring.io/blog/2016/06/10/spring-framework-4-3-goes-ga
Seems to me  Hibernate 5.2 is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I belive that correct answer is Hibernate 4.* try with Hibernate Core 4.3.6.Final.

Comment: You can also use Hibernate 3.x (although deprecated) or 5.x (as mentioned in other answers) with Spring 4.x.

Answer (score 0):

From the **Spring** point of view with Spring 4.3.2 you can use **any** Hibernate version up to the latest 5.2. For example i have used Spring with Hibernate 4.3.7 and Hibernate 5.0.7 so there does not have to be an exact match of versions.